# jquery syntax error

Tags: javascript, html, touch

I get a syntax error with this and I guess(?) it's because of the $??? How else should it be?

```
            case 2: // move event
                    if ( (swipeDirection === 'down')
                       $(".latest_img").fadeTo("slow", 1.0); // The white box is completely 100%
                       $(".latest_img").hover(function(){
                       $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.1); // The white box fades away
                       },function(){
                       $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0); // The white box stays away after finger leaves image
                       });
                     } else {
                document.getElementById('swipe-frame').style.backgroundImage = "url(11.png)";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a extra ( and are missing a { on the if statement line ...

```
                case 2: // move event
                    if (swipeDirection === 'down') {
                       $(".latest_img").fadeTo("slow", 1.0); // The white box is completely 100%
                       $(".latest_img").hover(function(){
                       $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.1); // The white box fades away
                       },function(){
                       $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0); // The white box stays away after finger leaves image
                       });
                     } else {
                document.getElementById('swipe-frame').style.backgroundImage = "url(11.png)";
```